# Selected item in listbox unreadable because of the color

Tags: wpf, colors, listbox, selecteditem, background-foreground

I dynamically create a collection of stackpanels in my listbox. In this stackpanel are contained labels and checkbox horizontally aligned.

The problem is when I click on a stackpanel, the selection is unreadable because the line become dark-blue whereas the letters stay black so black on blue, you see nothing. 
How can I dynamically change the forecolor of the selected elements in the stackpanel? I say dynamically and not in the xml file, because all those elements are dynamically created from a database.

I have code similar to this:

```
foreach (var utilis in item.user)
{
    StackPanelWithID ligne = new StackPanelWithID();
    ligne.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    ligne.ID = utilis.TRIGRAMME;
    ligne.Height = 21;
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Width = 120;
    Label l2 = new Label();
    l2.Width = 145;
    CheckBox cbEntretien = new CheckBox();
}
```

---

contentpresenter won't work... I tried several way to position it...
So, I found a way to circle the problem ...
in the app.xaml :

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
                        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Thus the background of selected items is clearer so that the user can still read text of the selected listboxitems.

and every listboxitem is concerned.

and yet... I would love to know how on earth it's possible to change the selected item's text color in list box.. if I manage to get the answer I'll keep you in touch...

---

I did this...

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">

                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                        Value="Red"/>

                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

but stll not working, it says the trigger property can't be found in ControlTemplate... 
I tried to add it after the trigger property, but not working either...

---

I tried something like this in the App.xaml :
"

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" <!--can't find the text property so try to act on the Background color to set it to a different color than dark blue-->
                                            Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>"
```

and in the particular xaml file where my listbox is :

```
<ListBox Margin="9,64,8,313" Loaded="lstUtilisateurs_Loaded" Name="lstUtilisateurs" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SimpleListBoxItem}"/>
```

but when executing, nothing appears anymore in the listbox, nothing... I don't get it...

Comment: Your object is created dynamically, but the style can be set statically. For example, you can use the Control Template in WPF.

Comment: When you say you dynamically create stackpanels for the list box, do you mean you create them programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I mean programmatically sorry
what I have is something like that :
"  foreach (var utilis in item.user)
                { StackPanelWithID ligne = new StackPanelWithID();
                    ligne.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                    ligne.ID = utilis.TRIGRAMME;
                    ligne.Height = 21;
                    Label l = new Label();
                    l.Width = 120;
                    Label l2 = new Label();
                    l2.Width = 145;
                    CheckBox cbEntretien = new CheckBox();...
I'm gonna try templates but it's quite hard for me..

Comment: Yeah, WPF template is quite complicated. I suggest you grab a book about WPF. The template engine is actually extremely powerful and fun to play with.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if it still matters (last answer was on Mar 25 2010), but for the people who are still wondering how to accomplish this I did it this way:

In the Style part:

```
    <Style x:Key="myLBStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

        <Style.Resources>

            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/> <!-- makes the background color transparent, removes backcolor border-->


            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/> <!-- Sets the textcolor of the selected text to red -->

        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

In the Listbox I use then the ItemContainerStyle property like this:

ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myLBStyle}

Took me a while to find, but here it is. Hope that someone can use it!

Also handy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms603164.aspx

Best Regards,

Sam